# There an elegant way to pass two methods to a callback?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, carrierwave

In my `Uploader` for Carrierwave, I have this:

```
  after :store, :delete_tmp_dir
  after :store, :zencode
```

I initially tried doing `after :store, :delete_tmp_dir, :zencode` but that threw an error.

Even though my version is working, is there anyway to call both in 1 line?

Comment: Judging from the [source](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb) - no, there isn't.

Comment: That's what I thought @Kitto. Ok add it as an answer and I will accept.